# AccountManagerCallback is not working with kitkat

Tags: android, twitter, accountmanager

I am using android account manager to authenticate twitter account.It is working fine for jellybean but for kitkat accountmanager callback is not coming.Here is my sample code

```
    accountManager.getAuthToken(twitterAccount, Constants.TWITTER_TOKEN,
            null, (Activity) mContext, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {


                @Override
                public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> amf) {
                    try {
                        Bundle b = amf.getResult();
                        OAUTH_TOKEN = b
                                .getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);

                        if (OAUTH_SECRET != null && OAUTH_TOKEN != null) {

                            authenticate();

                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Error while getting token",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            }, null);
```

Note:Constants.TWITTER_TOKEN = "com.twitter.android.oauth.token";